# How do I add my custom application in group/chat tab in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I followed the steps listed in MS Teams official documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/add-tab

I am trying to add my CakePHP web application into teams/group chat. I also tried creating configuration page to communicate between MS Teams and my web application but it didn't worked.

I have used CakePHP framework for my web app hence using it's default layout to create configuration page. Below is the code I have added in default layout page.

```
<script src="https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.8.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>

<script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();

    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            websiteUrl: "My website URL",
            contentUrl: "My content URL(which is same as my website URL)",
            entityId: "unique entity id that is mentioned in the app manifest file",
            suggestedDisplayName: "My tab name"
            });
        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });

    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true); 
</script>
```

I am not getting any error either but after adding my web app in tab, save button is disabled hence I am unable to save tab.

Refer this image:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the docs more carefully on this - the Configuration page needs to tell Teams when it's done any configuration work it needs to do. As an example, if you add a SharePoint tab in Teams, it gives the user the chance to choose *what* from SharePoint they want to show, so this configuration page is essential. If you *don't* need to offer the user any configuration, you can just put a static message on the page, but you still need to notify Teams that the configuration is 'complete', which you do by calling the Teams JS Library, something like this:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();

microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            websiteUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com",
            contentUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com/yourtab",
            entityId: "myTab",
            suggestedDisplayName: "MyNewTab"
            });
        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });

    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
});
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page).

Comment: I tried adding this configuration given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page) same as you mentioned in your comment but it didn't worked. I also tried setting `microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true)` directly after `microsoftTeams.initialize();` but save button is still disabled.

Comment: oh good point, I forgot to mention the `microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);` - updated the answer for future viewers. That should be pretty much it though - if it's not working, can you post an updated code sample. Do you have any interaction *required* on your config page (like the user needs to set any settings)?

Comment: No, for now user don't need to set any settings. That's why I used `microsoftTeams.initialize();` so that I can directly enable save button. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Otherwise I will post my code sample next.

Comment: Please post the sample

Comment: the only thing I can think that might make a difference is wrapping everything in `microsoftTeams.getContext`. I've updated the sample above - please try it and let me know if it changes anything.

Comment: Tried wrapping everything in `microsoftTeams.getContext` but it didn't worked either. Later found that browser is showing below error when I am trying to add tab. In Chrome, I am getting this - `Refused to frame 'my-website-url' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src blob: data: https: mailto: ms-appx-web: ms-excel: ms-powerpoint: ms-visio: ms-word: onenote: pdf: local.teams.office.com:* localhost:* msteams: sip: sips: ms-whiteboard-preview:".`

Comment: In FireFox getting this - `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at my-website-url (“frame-src”).`. Where as personal tab for my app is opening fine on both the browsers.

Comment: And this is how I am setting CSP Headers - `Header set Content-Security-Policy "child-src 'self' teams.microsoft.com;"`